# is this way of using current_user from Flask-Login safe?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm having trouble with understanding how current_user from Flask-Login library works. For example when two users access the same route at the same time and withing its function I call multiple modules that also use the current_user as an import. I will elaborate more with some code:

I have this route called update_account(I removed some parts because they are not related to my question):

```
@users.route('/account/user/<username>/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_account(username):
    update_account_form = UpdateForm()
    if update_account_form.validate_on_submit():
        #here we handle updating from another module
        if AccountManager.update_account(update_account_form): #retuns True if no errors has occured
            flash('Your account has been successfully updated', "success")
            return redirect(url_for('users.update_account', username=current_user.username))
        flash('Your client matched max requests', "warning")
        return redirect(url_for('users.update_account', username=current_user.username))
    return render_template('account/update.html', update_form=update_account_form)
```

My question is about the part I call `AccountManager.update_account(update_account_form)` because im not passing any of current_users data instead i'm importing current_user in that module as well and thats how I get the data. Below is how I implemented that:

```
   from flask_login import login_user, current_user 
 
   class AccountManager:
        @staticmethod
        def update_account(account_form):
            if current_user.request_counter >= 5:
                return False
            current_user.username = account_form.username.data.strip()
            current_user.email = account_form.email.data.strip()
            if account_form.change_password.data:
                current_user.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(account_form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
            db.session.commit()
            return True
```

My question is right here. Is this safe? Should I pass current_user as a parameter instead of importing it here? because maybe if another request comes the current_user changes and this method will change someone else data.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is fine.

`current_user` is dependent on the request context so you will not get a different user just because another user's request came in before you finished processing the first.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate more on what you mean by the "request context". when does it change and so on...

Comment: The flask [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/) can explain it better than I can.

Comment: tnx for the link. I didnt know where to loop up. and btw can you please correct me if i'm wrong. What I understood is that Flask will never handle two request at the same time and that is what assures us that we are calling the correct data.

Comment: What assures us this happens is that the docs say so. This is a core feature of a web server, to handle independent requests. It's unlikely to be a broken feature. How this is technically accomplished is beyond my knowledge.